# Can we solve a decision problem with two identical answers like $false\equiv(\lambda f.\lambda y.y)$ or $0\equiv(\lambda f.\lambda n.n)$?

Tags: lambda-calculus, normal-forms

as the title says

Can we solve a decision problem with two identical answers like $false\equiv(\lambda f.\lambda y.y)$ or $0\equiv(\lambda f.\lambda n.n)$?

if no why? and if yes then why can't we decide whether a lambda term is in normal form or not?

thanks

Comment: What is a decision problem with two identical answers? A decision problem is described with an input and a question. An answer (or two) is not part of the description of a decision problem. I am sorry, but your question makes little sense.

Comment: @Nathaniel I mean instead of answering a question with $1$ or $0$ we instead answer with $false$ or $0$. a lambda term can evaulate to a single expression but variable names can be different consider these two examples: ```console.log(((e => (c => x => y => c(x)(y))(e)(y=>y)(n=>n))(x=>y=>x)).toString())```
```
console.log(((e => (c => x => y => c(x)(y))(e)(y=>y)(n=>n))(x=>y=>y)).toString())```

Comment: In a decision problem, there are only two possible answers: "yes" or "no". That's it.

Comment: @Nathaniel can you explain why is it impossible to write a function that return $-0$ as "yes" and $0$ as no?

Answer (score 1):

This does not work in lambda calculus. One of the rules for evaluating lambda calculus terms is [α-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B1-conversion), which allows variable names to be changed at any time for any reason, as long as they do not conflict. There's no way that a program can arrange to put certain variable names in certain places as a kind of signal, because they could be arbitrarily renamed.

In general, if two answers are identical, they are the same answer, so your question is asking whether a decision problem can be answered with the same answer twice, e.g. can the halting problem be "solved" by a solver that outputs "no" if the program halts and "no" if the program does not halt. This is trivially possible, and provides no useful information because it does not actually tell us the answer.

Comment: I found out that the diagonalization argument does not work for call by value lambda calculus so we don't need this trick to work

Comment: @raoof please explain?

Comment: if we use call by value strategy in lambda calculus then diagonalization argument fails because we need to evaluate the argument before calling the function so no counter example can be constructed, diagonalization for turing machines has another problem it assume you can test to see whether the tape is blank/0, a halting decider can output 0, 1, 01, 001, 0001, ...

Comment: @raoof so you're saying the evaluation doesn't halt in some cases.

Comment: yes when you evaluate the argument first then evaluation might not halt without even calling the function

Comment: @raoof okay so there is an item on the diagonal where the evaluation does not halt. That's all we need to know. If the evaluation does not halt, then it's not a halting decider. Evaluation of a halting decider always halts.

Comment: no you didn't get the point, the point is that the halting decider can correctly return 0/False and the supposed counter example also does not halt because it is not a counter example under call by value strategy

Comment: @raoof Oh, it's impossible to evaluate the halting decider program by itself (without calling it)? Then it's obviously impossible to call it so it can't give you any answer so it's not a halting decider

Comment: no the halting decider accept Godel's encoding of a lambda term using church numerals as input so it's arguments always have a normal form

Comment: @raoof oh so it's impossible to evaluate the number? the number contains an infinite loop?

Comment: no, when you try to come up with a counter example using diagonalization then your counter example does not work because 'False Loop 1' does not halt under call by value strategy and the halting decider correctly returned False, you have to look at how people argue for undecidability of normal form for lambda calculus

Comment: @raoof So you have used lambda-calculus-call-by-name to make a program that decides whether lambda-calculus-call-by-value programs halt? Then you cannot feed the program as its own input because they are written in different programming languages. Even if you would use the same Gödel number, that number means a different program when interpreted in a different language, so you are not really running the program on itself.

Comment: no, I claim that it is logically possible that there is a call by value lambda calculus program that accept a Godel number of lambda term and decide whether the lambda term has a normal form under call by value strategy

Comment: in another words I don't have any reason to believe in undecidability

Comment: @raoof okay, diagonalize it, what now? You have a LCCBV program that does not terminate when you call it with its own Gödel number. Since it doesn't always terminate, it's not a halt decider.

Comment: what do you mean "diagonalize it" ? I'm saying diagonalization does not work

Comment: @raoof you wrote a program in the LCCBV language that takes a Gödel number as an argument, returns false if the program corresponding to that Gödel number doesn't halt when passed the number as an argument, and doesn't halt if that program does halt. So what happens if I pass it its own Gödel number? Does it halt or not? You haven't solved anything. The same problem is still there.

Comment: hahh..., I didn't wrote any program yet I said there is a LCCBV function let's call it h that when given a Godel number of a lambda term it return 0 if the lambda term does not have a normal form and return 1 if the lambda term have a normal form, now if you pass h it's own Godel number it returns 1 because a lambda function/abstraction is always in a normal form

Comment: @raoof okay? you can do that in any language - you can make a program that returns 1 if something is a program and 0 if it isn't. What does it have to do with halting?

Comment: are you familiar with a lambda calculus normal form problem or halting problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147184/discussion-between-user253751-and-raoof).